# AlarmManager does not work when screen is locked

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am having some difficulties to implement a service that should run periodically.
The app works fine when the screen is on, and even if the app is removed from the recent tasks. But when the device is locked, the app stops and even when the screen turns on again the service does not return.
I had implemented a WakefulBroadcastReceiver with an action to SCREEN_ON, but it works only when the application is alive, it does not work when there is only a service running.
The Service and the WakefulBroadcastReceiver are declared like this in my AndroidManifest:

```
<service android:name=".FeedService" />
<receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I also added the following permissions to my AndroidManifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

This is my WakefulBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class AutoStart extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Feed", "AutoStart.onReceive");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, FeedService.class));
    }
}
```

And this is my Service:

```
public class FeedService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("Feed", "FeedService.onStartCommand");
        stopSelf();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Feed", "FeedService.onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // I want to restart this service again in 5 seconds
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.set(
                alarm.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + (5000),
                PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, FeedService.class), 0)
        );
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity I start the service with:

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.set(
                alarm.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + (5000),
                PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, FeedService.class), 0)
        );
```

It's critical to my application keep this service running and I don't understand why it is not happening.
Could someone explain me how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my problem.
For some reason, even if I had requested WAKE_LOCK in the manifest file and registered my BroadcastReceiver in the Activity, my app does not have a permission to continues alive after the screen lock. I found an option on my device where it can be specified in settings>protected apps. So I just checked this option e now my service is working fine. I do not know if this option is checked automaticaly when the app is installed from Google Play (I hope so), but this option wasn't checked in my case.

Comment: No it won't be checked automatically